# upload a deobfuscation and symbol file

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mobile

I upload an app on `google play store`. I am using `xamarin / visual studio` and I have `bundle` my app. so this is aab, not apk. also I am using visual studio so I dont have gradle file

it is giving me 2 warnings

> ```
> Warning-1
> This App Bundle contains Java/Kotlin code, which might be obfuscated. We recommend you upload a deobfuscation file to make your crashes and ANRs easier to analyze and debug. Learn More
>
> Warning-2
> This App Bundle contains native code, and you've not uploaded debug symbols. We recommend you upload a symbol file to make your crashes and ANRs easier to analyze and debug. Learn More
> ```

**My Question:** how do i create deobfuscation & symbol files? are these just empty text files?

**On Google Play store console** - I found a section where I can upload `mapping` & `symbol files`, but not `deobfuscation file`

> App Bundle Explorer > Downloads > Assets >
>
> - Re-Trace mapping file > upload
> - Native Debug Symbols > upload

Answer (score -2):

For this, you can refer to document [Preparing an Application for Release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/release-prep/?tabs=windows).

You can follow the following steps to build the app for release:

**Specify the Application Icon** – Each Xamarin.Android application should have an application icon specified. Although not technically necessary, some markets, such as Google Play, require it.

**Version the Application** – This step involves initializing or updating the versioning information. This is important for future application updates and to ensure that the users are aware of which version of the application they have installed.

[**Shrink the APK**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/release-prep/?tabs=windows#shrink_apk) – The size of the final APK can be substantially reduced by using the Xamarin.Android linker on the managed code and ProGuard on the Java bytecode.

[**Protect the Application**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/release-prep/?tabs=windows#protect_app) – Prevent users or attackers from debugging, tampering, or reverse engineering the application by disabling debugging, obfuscating the managed code, adding anti-debug and anti-tamper, and using native compilation.

**Set Packaging Properties** – Packaging properties control the creation of the Android application package (APK). This step optimizes the APK, protects its assets, and modularizes the packaging as needed. Additionally, you can provide your users with an Android App Bundle that's optimized for their devices.

**Compile** – This step compiles the code and assets to verify that it builds in Release mode.

**Archive for Publishing** – This step builds the app and places it in an archive for signing and publishing.

Especially part [Shrink the APK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/release-prep/?tabs=windows#shrink_apk) and [Protect the Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/release-prep/?tabs=windows#protect_app).

Pay attention to [Application Protection with Dotfuscator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/release-prep/?tabs=windows#application-protection-with-dotfuscator):

Even with debugging disabled, it is still possible for attackers to re-package an application, adding or removing configuration options or permissions. This allows them to reverse-engineer, debug, or tamper with the application. [Dotfuscator Community Edition (CE)](https://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator) can be used to obfuscate managed code and inject runtime security state detection code into a Xamarin.Android app at build time to detect and respond if the app is running on a rooted device.

Dotfuscator CE is included with Visual Studio . To use Dotfuscator, click `Tools` > `PreEmptive Protection` - `Dotfuscator`.

To configure Dotfuscator CE, please see [Using Dotfuscator Community Edition with Xamarin](https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/pro/userguide/en/getting_started_xamarin.html). Once it is configured, Dotfuscator CE will automatically protect each build that is created.